# Internet connection only through VPN after forced shut down

Tags: network-manager, vpn, proxy

When on campus, I can only access the internet via the university's VPN. The connection is established by the Cisco Annyconnect Client (version 4.1).
I also set the proxy in the browser. All according to [the RZ's manual](https://www.rrz.uni-hamburg.de/services/netz/vpn/vpn-linux.html)

**Here's what happened:** While being on campus and being connected via VPN, my system froze and I had to shut it down forcefully by pressing the power button.
After a reboot and back at home, I discovered, that I could not access any sites other than the university's when not being tunneled via VPN.
Same thing for mails: I can still access the university's mail, but not connection can be established to the other providers IF I'm not logging in with VPN.

Strange thing: Even when tunneling via VPN, I cannot access some Flash player content that I was able to access before.

**Here's what I tried so far:**

- I reset the proxy settings in the browser via "about:config" - didn't help
- I upgraded the Cisco client to the latest version - didn't help
- I even restored my system by a backup that was done before the incident - didn't help
- I checked IPv4 and v6 routes: in all my LAN and W-LAN connections, IPv4 is set to "automatically (DHCP)" and IPv6 is also set to "automatically". For both, there are no additional routes that I defined.

There are no settings I can restore in the VPN client itself.
The internet connection itself is absolutely intact and its settings didn't change.

Finally, **here's what's my goal:**
I want to reset my system, all software affected and/or the VPN connection in such a way that I can again access all content without the necessity to tunnel into the university's network first.

All explanations and suggestions are appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit on a Lenovo X230]